# React Hooks Wrapper not getting updated after state change in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

**Current behaviour**

I'm using a functional component with a `setState` hook in `useEffect`. The state variable that is set inside `useEffect` is wrapped over the return statement to render the JSX for the component.

When I debug into it, the component renders with the correct state variable but my wrapper in my test does Not show the correct information.

`wrapper.update()` isn't fixing this issue.

Below is a snippet of what I am trying to achieve:

```
const DummyComponent= ({}) => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      setSelected(true)
    }, [someDependency])

    return (
      { 
         selected && (
         <div id= 'container'>
            {childComponents}
          </div>)
       }
    );
    })

it('test', () => {
     const wrapper= mount( <DummyComponent  /> ); 
    wrapper = wrapper.update(); // this doesn't fix my problem   
    wrapper.find('#container')first().props().onClick();
    expect(wrapper.toMatchSnapshot());
});
```

I am getting the below error:

```
Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.
```

**Expected Behaviour**

After state update in `useEffect` re-render should be triggered in test case and element with `id="container"` should be found.

Note: This is **not same** as https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2305

Comment: It should be `.find('#container')`.

Comment: @EstusFlask that was a typo, I corrected my question. issue is not this typo

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the rendering code in the `act` [test utility method](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-test-components-that-use-hooks)? It helps with a lot of issues when testing Hooks.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. There's no someDependency and onClick. This means that your real case may differ from that you posted

Comment: @kidney you mean to wrap "mount( <DummyComponent  /> ) " in act, right?

Comment: Yeah, that would be my guess.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me there's some other problem with your real code (maybe some promise-based code invoked in the effect?). Here's a working example based on your snippet:

```
const DummyComponent = ({}) => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(false);
    const [result, setResult] = React.useState("");

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setSelected(true);
    }, []);

    return selected && <div id='container' onClick={() => setResult("test")}>
        <label>{result}</label>
    </div>;
};

it('test', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<DummyComponent/>);
    act(() => {
        wrapper.find('#container').first().props().onClick();
    });
    expect(wrapper.find("label").text()).toEqual("test");
});
```

The `act` is actually needed only for interaction with the component itself, not for after-render effect.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that when you first mount the component, it does not render anything, because `selected` is false. So, when you search for `'#container'`, you don't get anything.

If the `update` is enough, then it should probably be executed *before* the `wrapper.find()`, so that the component is rendered with `selected` true. But React is asynchronous and I suspect that this will not be enough…

Answer (score -1):

I fixed my problem, actually I need to assign my component to a different wrapper and then update the wrapper and then check for updates on the wrapper instead of the component. Below is the snippet:

```
it('test', () => {

     const component= mount( <DummyComponent  /> ); 
     const wrapper = component.update();  
     wrapper.find('#container')first().props().onClick();
     expect(wrapper.toMatchSnapshot());

});
```

This will have the updated component